# rethinkdb delete nested property

Tags: updates, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have following table structure -

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "prop": {
    "1": {
      "bunch-of-stuffs": "foo"
    },
    "2": {
      "bunch-of-stuffs": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to remove "prop" with the key "2" so that it looks like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "prop": {
    "1":{
      "bunch-of-stuffs": "foo"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried the update, but it doesn't work -

> r.table("sad").get(1).update({"prop":{"1":{ "bunch-of-stuffs": "foo"
>   }}})

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RethinkDB: Javascript - How to deleted nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006585/rethinkdb-javascript-how-to-deleted-nested-objects)

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case you can simply call the `.replace` function to replace the whole document as you know every value:

```
r.table("sad").get(1).replace({
 "id":1,
 "prop":{
    "1":{ "bunch-of-stuffs": "foo" }
  }
})
```

If you know the id of the "prop" that you want to delete, you can use the replace like follows, to avoid sending the whole json document over the wire:

```
r.table("sad").get(1).replace(function(doc){
      return {"id":1, "prop": doc("prop").without("2")}
})
```

Comment: I know that will work, but my table "sad" has almost 50 properties and  I do not wish to send large json over the network to my node backend. Is there any alternative to update the document by sending information about the concerned property?

Comment: please check out the edit i made. Do you know the id of the prop that you want to delete ("2") ?